# Array is empty until async pipe is resolved

Tags: angular, asynchronous, promise, pipe, observable

I am working on a async filter pipe that filters an array based on an input that is provided by the user.

When the user types an input, the filter pipe is triggered and the filter result is returned with 1 second of delay. This is achived by using promises.

The async pipe is responsible for waiting for the promise until it(the promise) resolves the result.

My problem is that during the delay (when data is in the process of being resolved), the result rendered in HTML is empty until the data is resolved by promise. I dont want HTML to display empty result rather I want the previous array list to be shown in HTML until the promise is resolved. Then it should show the new filtered result.

Filter pip function in angular. Promise is resolved after observable is subscribed. after 1000 ms

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    resolver: Function = null;

    transform(arr: any[], search: string) {
        
        let promise = new Promise<any[]>((res, rej) => {
            this.resolver = res;
        });

        from(arr).pipe(concatMap(item => of(item).pipe(delay(1000)))
        ).subscribe(timedItem => {
            this.resolver(arr.filter(x => x.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== -1));
        });

        return promise;
    }
}
```

In HTML template async is used with filter pipe and myFilter is an input argumnet to filter the array.

```
<select-dropdown [(ngModel)]="selectValue">
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myFilter">
        <select-option *ngFor="let item of list | filter : myFilter | async; let i = index" [value]="i">{{ item + ' ' + i }}</select-option>
</select-dropdown>
```

Need help in this one.

Comment: Why is there a delay? If you want to stop unnecessary searches, you should use the debounceTime Operator instead (very common pattern in this particular use case). Cant check code on mobile but it seems to me that operator is more like what you want to achieve.

Comment: Maybe you need to do `async` pipe first: `<select-option *ngFor="let item of list | async | filter : myFilter; ...`